# Type-casting int array to char pointer and reading in-between values of 2 indices

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose there is an integer ( of 4 bytes each) array in memory

```
memory location:  10   14   18   22
value:          [ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ][ 4 ]
```

if I use a character pointer 'p' as shown

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a[] ={1,2,3,4};
    char *p = (char*)a; //character pointer
    cout<<(int)(*(p+0))<<endl;
    cout<<(int)(*(p+1))<<endl; //point A
    cout<<(int)(*(p+2))<<endl;
    cout<<(int)(*(p+4))<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the output is

```
1
0
0
2
```

Why am I getting 0 instead of a garbage value (consider in Point A, we should get an integer value equal to last 3 bytes of a[i] + first byte of a[1]). I am just a beginner, I am sorry if I have done any silly mistake

what I want to do is let's take

```
a[0] = 2147483647
a[1] = 2147483646
then in bits 
a[0] = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
a[1] = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111110
taking a char pointer p = (int*)(&a[0] + 1)
should hold 11111111 11111111 11111111 (<-from a[0], from a[1]->) 11111111
hence (int) *p should be again 2147483647
```

Comment: Because when you have a 4-byte `int`, and it holds values less than 256, not only the first byte holds the value, but all the other three bytes are zero. They must be zero, and if you think about it for a little while, you should be able to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why am I getting 0 instead of a garbage value (consider in Point A, we should get an integer value equal to last 3 bytes of a[i] + first byte of a[1])

Because the code you wrote doesn't do that. You have an array of `int`s that you access with a char pointer. So, `*(p+0)` is going to give you the first byte. `*(p+1)` the second, and so on. You're cast to `int` is unnecessary (it only converts the resulting number to `int`), it happens too late. You need to recast the pointer value:

```
std::cout << *(int*)(p+1);
```

Note that this is undefined behavior though.

Comment: This totally has undefined behaviour, so "you need to" seems like bad teaching. Other than that, good answer though

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I always thought that it was implementation defined... Fixed

Comment: You'd need to `memcpy` or `std::copy` to do this in a well-defined way (which has the added benefit of fixing the alignment problem)

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting 0 instead of a garbage value

Why do you think that 0 is not a garbage value? There is no guarantee that a garbage value isn't 0. 0 is a perfectly valid value for garbage.

That said, you're not printing anything that has a garbage value. There is no padding between elements of an array, and `int` itself doesn't contain padding, and there are no uninitialised objects in the array.

`int` consists of one or more bytes. On your system, it happens to be 4 bytes. `p+0` points to the first byte, `p+1` points to the second byte, `p+4` points to the first byte of the second integer. If neither the first nor the second byte has the value 0, then the integer couldn't possibly represent 1.

> reading in-between values of 2 indices

There is no space between elements of an array, so there is nothing to read. You're reading different parts of an element in the array.

> (consider in Point A, we should get an integer value equal to last 3 bytes of a[i] + first byte of a[1]).

You can achieve this like so:

```
int i;
std::memcpy(&i, p + 1, sizeof i);
std::cout << i;
```

Comment: with reading in-between values of 2 indices

I meant some part of a[0] & some part of a[1]

Comment: @Snowfox the last part I've edited in shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, 0 is a perfectly valid "garbage value".

But it's moot here, because you're not actually converting 4 bytes to integer — you're extracting *one* byte, then converting it to integer. You'd have to reinterpret the `char*` as an `int*` (then dereference it) to do what you say you're doing, and then we come to:

#### Undefined behaviour

Manipulating memory like this has *undefined behaviour*. Anything can happen when you try to pretend that a non-`int` is an `int`.

That's not just standardese, or puritanism, or pedanticism. It's true, and it has real-world, practical outcomes, like the one you've seen.

The act of translating the abstract program you've described using C++ words, into a real-world, practical program that a computer can understand, is *unbelievably complicated*. The compiler does not take your lines one at a time and just naively rewrite them into code that is the same but in a machine language. It reads your whole source code, understands what you want the program it describes to you, then creates a brand new program in an entirely different, unrelated, separate language that has the same result. To do this quickly it also takes some shortcuts.

When you write a program whose behaviour is undefined, you break this process. You simply cannot assume that "we should get an integer value equal to last 3 bytes of a[i] + first byte of a[1]". That was perhaps more likely to be true in the 1970s, but computers are really complicated, modern ones more than antique ones.

Short version: don't do this.